# Was versteht man unter einer "russischen Glühbirne"?

Tags: meaning, dialect, austrian

Ein Freund von mir hat vor Kurzem den Ausdruck "russische Birne" verwendet, um eine von der Decke direkt auf Kabel hängende Glühbirne zu bezeichnen. Passiert ist es in Österreich. Ich habe ein bisschen gegoogelt und den Begriff "[Russenluster](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russenluster)" mit derselben Bedeutung gefunden.

Was verstehen Muttersprachler unter einer "russischen Birne"? Eine Glühlampe von der Decke hängend? Einfach eine russische Birne, also Obst? Oder sogar einen russischen Kopf (etwa "nur er mit seiner russischen Birne konnte auf so eine Idee kommen")?

Comment: Du hast eine plausible, unzweideutige Erklärung, was "Russenbirne" bedeutet - wieso willst Du jetzt, dass es "Obst" oder "Kopf" bedeutet? Weil Dein Freund kein Muttersprachler ist?

Comment: Was zu den anderen Antworten noch zu ergänzen ist: offiziell heißt diese Art der Montage _Baufassung_ (oder ugs. manchmal _Rohbaufassung_), nach dem intendierten Gebrauch. Was einen nicht daran hindert, sie trotzdem dauerhaft einzusetzen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ich kenne die Verwendung des Attributs *russisch* mit der Bedeutung "improvisiert, unfachmännisch, primitiv". Ich habe etwa den Ausdruck *russische Methode* gehört; damit wurde die Methode bezeichnet, eine Maschine zu reparieren, indem man einmal draufhaut. Aber auch in anderen Zusammenhängen wird das Attribut verwendet, um eine funktionierende, aber primitive Lösung zu bezeichnen.

Diese Bedeutung passt in deinem Beispiel, weil die Glühbirne nur in der Fassung angebracht war, ohne einen Lampenschirm. Der Begriff bezieht sich also hier nicht speziell auf Lampen, sondern auf die Art und Weise, wie die Lampe montiert war.

Offenkundig sind hier nationalistische Stereotype im Spiel. Die Stereotype, die hier am Werk sind, beinhalten die Vorstellung von einer Minderwertigkeit der russischen Kultur, Zivilisation und Technologie. In meinen Augen schwingen hier Assoziationen an die sozialistische Vergangenheit Russlands (und die Vorstellung, dass im Alltag aufgrund von Materialmangel viel improvisiert werden musste) mit. Ich würde vermuten, dass die Geschichte dieser Stereotype weit zurückreicht, und insbesondere auch vom Bild Russlands in Deutschland im 2. Weltkrieg, vom Kalten Krieg, von der Rolle Russlands in der Beziehung zur DDR, sowie von der Wahrnehmung Russlands nach 1990 geprägt wurde.

Offensichtlich handelt es sich hier um ein Vokabular, das diskriminierende gruppenbezogene Stereotype reproduziert. Ich würde daher nicht empfehlen, diesen Ausdruck zu verwenden.

Comment: Aus der (berechtigten oder unberechtigten) Annahme eines Materialmangels und daraus resultierender Improvisation, welche wiederum eher technisch minderwertige Resultate zur Folge hat, auf die Annahme einer "Minderwertigkeit der russischen Kultur [und] Zivilisation" zu schließen, halte ich doch für ziemlich gewagt.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Dass diese Vorstellung in dem Ausdruck mitschwingt, ist natürlich eine schwer zu überprüfende Hypothese. Falls sie dich nicht überzeugt, lass einfach einen Downvote da :) Dass es in einer bestimmten Weise um die russische Kultur / Identität etc. geht, folgt für mich daraus, das man nicht "sozialistische Glühbirne", "sozialistische Methode", etc. sagt, sondern eben "russisch". Ich vermute, wie gesagt, dass hier ein lange etabliertes, im 2. WK und Kalten Krieg besonders kultiviertes Stereotyp am Werk ist. Es wäre hilfreich, zu wissen, wann diese Verwendungsweise aufgetaucht ist.

Comment: 'Dass es in einer bestimmten Weise um die russische Kultur / Identität etc. geht, folgt für mich daraus, das man nicht "sozialistische Glühbirne", "sozialistische Methode", etc. sagt, sondern eben "russisch".' - ok, wenn du davon ausgehen möchtest, dass sich diejenigen, die den Ausdruck geprägt haben, so genau darüber Gedanken gemacht haben. Mein Verdacht ist eher, dass sich jemand dachte: "Ich hab' in Russland immer wieder derartige Beleuchtungsprovisorien gesehen, also nenne ich das jetzt 'russische Glühbirne'!", ohne sich darüber den Kopf zu zerbrechen, ob das Vorkommen derartiger ...

Comment: ... Lichtinstallationen jetzt eher deckungsgleich mit "Russland" oder eher deckungsgleich mit "sozialistische Gesellschaften" ist.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Es ist ja nicht nur entscheidend, was sich die Erfinder:innen des Ausdrucks gedacht haben. Und es geht ja auch nicht nur um Lampen, sondern um das Attribut, das auch in anderen Zusammenhängen in dieser pejorativen Weise verwendet wird. Bei einer Korrelation eines eine Nation oder Ethnie bezeichnenden Adjektivs mit einer negativen Assoziation halte ich es für angebracht, von gruppenbezogenen Stereotypen auszugehen. Das macht für mich hier den Unterschied zu Ausdrücken wie "türkischer Kaffee".  Aber wir werden uns hier nicht allein durch Diskussion einig werden, fürchte ich.

Comment: Meiner Erfahrung nach schwingt in anderem Kontext im Gegenteil oft Bewunderung mit für die unterstellte Improvisationsfähigkeit und die einfachen, aber robusten Lösungen. Vgl. z.B. die weit verbreitete Legende zum [Weltraumkugelschreiber](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-nasa-spen/) oder die vielgerühmte Robustheit des [Kalaschnikow](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalaschnikow#Popul%C3%A4re_Fehleinsch%C3%A4tzungen)-Sturmgewehrs.

Comment: @JonathanScholbach: Würde es für Dich einen Unterschied machen, wenn Russen selbst das Wort "Russen~" oder "russisch" in der Art gebrauchen würden?

Comment: Diese Antwort ist im Prinzip richtig, übersieht aber, dass der Begriff "russischer Luster" weder in der ehemaligen DDR noch in der BRD entstanden ist, sondern in Österreich, wo dieser Begriff auch heute noch zum sprachlichen Allgemeingut gehört. Ursache war auch nicht die russische Kultur (die ich nicht als Minderwertig bezeichnen würde), sondern die Zeit des Mangels zwischen 1945 und 1955 während der russischen (eigentlich sowjetischen) Besatzung Ostösterreichs. Siehe auch [meine Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/71329/1487)

Comment: Das Meme "there I fixed it" in Worte gefasst. Die Russen sollen ja damals an der Front die Wasserhähne abgeschraubt haben in der Hoffnung, da kommt zuhause dann Wasser raus.

Answer (score 6):

Den Begriff *»russische Birne«* kenne ich nicht, sehr wohl hingegen den sehr häufigen *»russischen Luster«* oder den weit weniger häufig verwendeten *»Russenluster«* wie er in dem bereits in der Frage erwähnten [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russenluster) erwähnt wird. Siehe auch den Eintrag auf [ostarrichi.com](https://www.ostarrichi.com/wort/8737/russischer_Luster). Bei *»russische Birne«* fehlt der sarkastische Witz, der im *»russischen Luster«* steckt.

Dieser Begriff *»russischer Luster«* ist in Österreich (zumindest im Osten Österreichs) allgemein bekannt und wird auch häufig verwendet. Wenn eine Neubauwohnung an den ersten Mieter übergeben wird, sind nur diese russischen Luster als Beleuchtungskörper montiert.

Der Begriff *»Luster«* (in Deutschland angeblich *»Lüster«*?) bezeichnete ursprünglich einen mehrarmigen von der Decke hängenden prunkvoll gestalteten Kerzenhalter, auf dem dutzende, manchmal sogar mehr als 100 Kerzen montiert waren. Mit der Umstellung auf elektrische Beleuchtung wurden die Kerzen durch Glühbirnen ersetzt, der Name *»Luster«* für einen von der Decke hängenden Beleuchtungskörper mit zwei oder mehr Leuchtmitteln blieb. Jeder Kronleuchter ist ein Luster, aber nur sehr prunkvolle und große Luster sind Kronleuchter.

Beim *»russischen Luster«* ist der Begriff *»Luster«* sarkastisch gemeint.

Das Wort *»russisch«* bezieht sich wohl auf die Besatzung Österreichs durch die alliierten Streitkräfte nach dem zweiten Weltkrieg (1945 bis 1955, mit Nachwirkungen bis in die 1970er-Jahre), insbesondere auf die sowjetische Besatzung Ostösterreichs (Burgenland, Niederösterreich, Teile Oberösterreichs und Teile Wiens). In dieser Zeit herrschte Mangel, und wenn ein Gerät gerade mal den Mindestanforderungen entsprach, und vielleicht auch ständiger Wartung bedurfte, wurde es als *»russisch«* bezeichnet.

Das Wort *»russisch«* bezieht sich zumindest beim *»russischen Luster«* also nicht, wie in manchen Kommentaren vermutet wurde, auf die besondere Robustheit einfacher Konstruktionen, die man den Russen zuschrieb, sondern im Gegenteil auf mangelhafte improvisierte Lösungen, die aus purer Not in einer Zeit entstanden waren, als unter der verhassten Besatzung durch eine fremde Macht Mangel herrschte.

Damit einher geht auch die geographische Verbreitung dieses Begriffs, der eben genau dort allgemein bekannt ist, wo Österreich 10 Jahre lang von den Sowjets (die man mit den Russen gleichsetzte) besetzt war.

Comment: In Deutschland kenne ich den Begriff Lüster, aber er ist hier m.E. veraltet (vielleicht noch in der Fachsprache aktuell, das weiß ich nicht). Man verwendet praktisch nur noch "Kronleuchter", auch für die einfachsten Exemplare. Überlebt hat der Lüster im Wort  Lüsterklemme, das für eine Kabelverbindung in der E-Installation steht.

Comment: @HalvarF: Die von dir erwähnte Klemme heißt bei uns in Österreich *Lusterklemme.* Das Wort *Luster* (aus Lateinisch *lustrare* = hell machen über italienisch *lustrare* = glänzend machen und französisch *lustre* = Schimmer, Glanz) ist in Österreich keineswegs veraltet. Es wird ungefähr gleich häufig verwendet wie "Heckenschere" oder "Laminat". Die umgelautete Version *Lüster* ist in Österreich weitgehend unbekannt (klingt zu sehr nach *lüstern = wollüstig* bei gleichzeitigem Fehlen einer semantischen Verbindung zu diesem Begriff).

Comment: Auch "russischer Kronleuchter" ist hier in Niederösterreich durchaus verbreitet als Bezeichnung für die Glühbirne in einer einfachen Fassung ohne Schirm.

Answer (score 2):

Das Attribut "russisch" wird gelegentlich genutzt, um improvisierte, leicht abenteuerliche Konstruktionen, Reparaturen etc. zu beschreiben - und natürlich stecken hinter einer solchen Verwendung jede Menge Clichés und ggf. auch Vorurteile; d.h. man sollte damit vorsichtig umgehen.

Für mich liegt der Ursprung darin, dass trotz Kenntnis der richtigen Vorgehensweise, aber mangels der eigentlich nötigen Materialien behelfsmäßig mit viel Improvisationstalent und auch handwerklichen Geschick auf das zurückgegriffen wurde, was verfügbar war, um das Ziel doch zu erreichen.

Um beim Beispiel Glühbirne zu bleiben: der Begriff ansich löst keine ganz konkrete Vorstellung aus, aber sicher etwas Improvisiertes, ich erwarte keine normale Lampe: Was macht man, wenn man Licht braucht, Strom hat, und eine Glühbirne, aber keine Fassung verfügbar ist? Eine einfache Methode ist, die Glühbirne direkt an das Kabel anzulöten. Eine andere wäre ggf. die Kabel der Decke so weit abzuisolieren, dass man sie mit etwas Klebeband hinreichend voneinander isoliert an die Glühbirne selbst ankleben und befestigen kann. Ziel in beiden Fällen erreicht - aber nach VDE ist es sicher nicht.

Spreche ich von einer "russischen Methode", so ist damit eher eine im weitesten Sinne robuste Methode gemeint, die auch in Anspielung auf die [Russen-Mafia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russische_Mafia) Mafia-Methoden beinhalten kann (je nach Kontext).

Eine Anekdote zu 'russische Lösung' (=einfach, aber funktional) ist die Urban Legend zum Space-Pen (die [hier](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-nasa-spen/) aber der ScientificAmerican widerlegt): Die Russen nahmen ganz simpel einen Bleistift. Der funktioniert immer, egal in welcher Richtung und unter Schwerelosigkeit - man braucht nur einen Anspitzer bzw. bei Druckminen-Stiften nichtmal das. Die Amerikaner haben langwierig und teuer den Space-Pen entwickelt, der auch in Schwerelosigkeit funktioniert...
Ähnlich könnte man sagen, dass die russische Methode ein kleines Loch in der Raumstation abzudichten mit einem Kaugummi an passender Stelle geht, während "die westliche Methode" wäre, erstmal den Spezialkleber hochzuschicken und dann mit einer Spezial-Spritze diesen in das Loch zu injizieren.